# SSRS special tablix formatting/filter

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am working in SQL Server 2008 R2. I am generating a report which is based on a transactional table. The table contains a field called `conval` which is either 1 or -1. The value is part of a constraint that contains 5 key fields. What I need to do in the report is if the net value of for any set of the other 4 primary key fields then do not print the line. If the net value is 1 print the line. While it is possible that a user could have entered a single value of -1, the occurrence is less than I need to deal with at this time.

For example if the values were `123,12A,Final,Complex,1` and `123,12A,Final,Complex,-1` and `123,12B,Final,Complex,1`

The only set that would print on the report would be `123,12B,Final,Complex,1`

Answer (score 0):

Have the table grouped by the first 4 fields. Now you can refer to the sum of the conval and check if it is 1. You could set a visibility expression like this:

```
=iif(sum(Fields!conval.Value, "MyGroup") = 1, False, True)
```

This will only show the results that have the net value of 1. Be sure to rename the field and group to match yours.